# Calculate to how many cubes one cube can be cut

Tags: code-golf, math

Imagine some cube which we can cut into smaller cubes without remaining pieces.

Find to how many cubes a cube can be cut.

For example, a cube can be cut into 8, 27 (obviously 3rd powers of integers) and 20 (19 small cubes plus one eight times the size of the others, see image).
See here some help: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeDissection.html

[image]
Program should take as input integer `n` (`0 <= n <= 1 000`) and print all numbers less or equal to `n` so that a cube can be cut into that number of cubes.
Suppose that cube can be cut into 1 cube and cannot into 0 cubes.

You can use only integral data-types (no arrays, objects etc) of size no greater than 64-bits.
Shortest code wins.

Comment: This has potential but you need to specify it more clearly. A cube can indeed be cut into 20 cubes: instead of cutting it into 27 cubes of side 1/3 the original, cut it into 19 cubes of side 1/3 the original and one which is 8 times larger (side 2/3 the original.) Yes I think a picture would be helpful

Comment: That's a pretty rough cube I've drawn, feel free to change it. At first sight this seems trivial but I think there's an interesting range around 125-216 (5^3-6^3.) It's probable that for very large numbers nearly all divisions are possible.

Comment: We will see whether all numbers after some threshold will be possible.

Comment: Not all are possible. For 125, for example, you obviously have 125, then the next few down will be replacing 8 cubes with one twice as large: 125, 118, 111, 104, 97. By the time you get to 97 you can also replace 27 cubes with one three times as large: 125-26=99. At this point it there could be a large range of options, except for the fact that only one size 3 cube will fit (that restriction does not apply for 216.) The math will get quite complicated. You might want to limit the `n` to a smaller number (say 1000) to be able to check if the programs are giving the right answer.

Comment: I changed it from code-golf to popularity-contest because it sounds like it's too complicated, also visualisation will be cool.

Comment: I would have left it as code-golf, and someone may bring a huge mathematical insight to this that will make it much easier. On the other hand it's your call and you're right about the visualisation.

Comment: The answer is actually here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeDissection.html

Comment: There's actually proof for this, for every n>47, a cube can be cut into n different cubes.

Comment: Since we have a fairly trivial solution now, you might want to change this back to code golf or put some *really* hard restriction on the submissions.

Comment: With that link help I have found 52 long solution in Mathematica. Should I post it in comment/make an answer?

Comment: Make it an answer. Stack Exchange encourages to answer your own questions. 52 bytes will be difficult to beat though, except for hardcoded answers. I think the reason you don't have any answers yet is because people know their calculations can't beat a hardcoded answer. I may post a hardcoded answer in C, but I'm reluctant to because it's against the spirit of the question.

Comment: I have hard-coded answer and that's why it not so interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Golfscript, 55 (or <s>43</s> 42)

```
{.:^}{.47>20{.^>^@- 7%|!|}:/~1/38/39/{}{;}if^(}while;]`
```

Can be tested [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Owo1Ngp7LjpefXsuNDc%2BMjB7Ll4%2BXkAtIDclfCF8fTovfjEvMzgvMzkve317O31pZl4ofXdoaWxlO11gCgo%3D) (just change the number on line 2) and only uses the array (last two chars of code) for clean printing, not for any collection or problem solving. If you leave it off, all results will be concatenated.

**Method:** Iterate down from given n: If current number is greater than 47 or of the form 1+7x, 20+7x, 38+7x, or 39+7x where x = any non-negative integer, then keep it on the stack, otherwise drop it.

**Short answer (43 bytes):**

<s>{:/6+,{7*/+}%|}:&;):a,48,^1&20&38&39&{a<},`</s>

```
):a,48,^1{:/6+,{7*/+}%|}:&~20&38&39&{a<},`
```

**Method:** Similar, but with a few set theory ops. This uses arrays so it's technically not an acceptable answer. Can be tested [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Owo1NgopOmEsNDgsXjF7Oi82Kyx7NyovK30lfH06Jn4yMCYzOCYzOSZ7YTx9LGA%3D). Btw: nobody ever said they had to be in any particular order ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Mathematica, 62 bytes (or 52)**

It's hardcoded answer, nothing interesting.

> `If[EvenQ@BitShiftRight[164015534735101,n],Print@n]~Do~{n,1000}`

This one is 52 bytes long but violates my rules - it uses large integers (powers of 2) and lists (Range).

> `Select[Range@1000,EvenQ@Floor[164015534735101/2^#]&]`

Answer (score 0):

## C, 72

```
i;main(){for(scanf("%d",&i);i;i--)0x952BD7AF7EFC>>i&1||printf("%d ",i);}
```

Another hardcoded answer. This counts downwards (there's nothing in the rules about the order the numbers have to be output in.) In theory it should work. The constant has a bit set to 1 for all the numbers into which a cube can NOT be cut, and a 0 for the numbers which can. In theory, the constant when right shifted by a very large number should be zero, so the large number should always be printed.

What's interesting is that in practice this does not work. The code above compiles and runs fine on GCC up to 65. But above that number there is a bug (or "feature") in the compiler. it interprets `0x952BD7AF7EFC>>i` as `0x952BD7AF7EFC>>i%64`. So it skips (for example) the numbers 66 through 71 (64+2 through 64+7).

To run in Visual Studio, a bit more boilerplate is needed (it doesn't let you get away with things like implied integers and `#include`s.) Once the program's up and running, it's fine up to 257... Then it skips 258 through 263 (256+2 through 256+7.) So it's taking `i%256.`

I may fix it later (if I can be bothered.) Moral: compiler manuals don't normally tell you the upper limit on bitshifts. There's a reason for that!

Comment: This uses exactly the same principle as mine answer)

Comment: Indeed, we even have basically the same constant (with bit zero unused and bit 1 representing the number 1.) In C I save a single byte by specifying the constant in hex. I have a `0` for bit zero, I could change it for a `1` like yours for the case i=0. But it never gets displayed anyway.

Comment: @steveverrill please explain how `NUM>>i` changes to `NUM>>i%64`. Also if a `64-bit` number is right shifted more than 64 times it should become `zero`

Comment: @Manav indeed it should become zero. As I say, the compiler has a bug. `NUM>>i` becomes `NUM>>(i%64)` or equivalently `NUM>>(i&63)`because the compiler is truncating the leftmost bits of `i` before performing the bitshift. GCC only considers only the rightmost 6 bits. Visual Studio has the same bug but is slightly better, considering only the rightmost 8 bits `NUM>>(i%256)`. Out of curiosity I will try Ideone when I get home from work.

Comment: ideone behaves exactly like GCC. http://ideone.com/EpKTpO

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```ruby
->n{1.upto(n){|i|i/7<777159>>i%7*3&7||p(i)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6v2lCvtKAkXyNPs7omsyZT39zG3Nzc0NTSzi5T1VzLWM28pqZAI1OztvZ/WrSlZex/AA)

Takes advantage of the fact that solutions occur modulo 7 (as a result of the fact that a cube can be dissected into 8 cubes, adding 7.)

Below are all solutions below 49 (there is a solution for all numbers over 49.) The magic number `777159` decimal = `2755707` octal encodes the lowest value of `i/7` for which a solution exists for each possible value of `i%7`.

```ruby
n%7=0                         not possible where i/7<7
n%7=1    1,8,15,22,29,36,43                      i/7<0
n%7=2                                            i/7<7 
n%7=3                 38,45                      i/7<5   
n%7=4                 39,46                      i/7<5
n%7=5                                            i/7<7
n%7=6        20,27,34,41,48                      i/7<2
```